# Crontab error: "/tmp/crontab.calJpk":5: bad day-of-month

Tags: linux, cron

I am trying to run a crontab with the expression given below. But i am getting bad day-of-month error.

My requirement is to run this code:

1. everyday except Sunday
2. every hour starting 2 am till 10pm

   0 2-22 ? * 0-6 * /usr/bin/python /my/location/to/python_code_for_cron/sampletest.py

Is there some issue with the cron expression or something else that i need to install?

FYI: I am using `crontab -e` to edit my crontab

Answer (score 3):

You just have too many arguments in there. Read `man -s5 crontab` for more info. The fields are:

```
minute hour day-of-month month day-of-week
```

Also, 0-6 is the same as * for day-of-week. Your line should read:

```
0 2-22 * * 1-6 /usr/bin/python /my/location/to/python_code_for_cron/sampletest.py
```